# How to add event listener to many markers on the map?

Tags: markers, leaflet

How can I add an event listener to many markers on the map?
I know how to add an event listener to a single marker say:

```
var marker = L.marker(...);
marker.on('dragend',function(){...});
```

So, how can I add an event listener to many markers on the map?

In jQuery, you can select objects like this (example):

```
$(".marker").on("click",function(){...});
```

So this code applies it to all things with class marker.

Is there something similar to this with Leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of your markers in an array.

```
var markerArray = [];
```

Every time you add a marker you push it to the array.

```
var marker = new L.marker(...);
markerArray.push(marker);
```

Then if you wanted to apply some event listener to each of the markers you just iterate over that list.

```
for(var i=0;i<markerArray.length;i++){
    markerArray[i].on("click",function(){...});
}
```

Note the above code couldn't be copy/pasted since I didn't actually write the L.marker options or event callback function, but you should be able to pick it up from there.

Comment: Thank, but now I have this issue:

When I write something like: markerArray[i].getLatLng(), it gives me this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLatLng' of undefined

Comment: Whats the issue? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Enrique Do you recall how you solved your issue?